# Iterate over an object properties with a property length being equal a number in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

Let us suppose that I have an object `const a = { length: 10, b: "c"}`.

Now I want to iterate over the properties of the  object using `$.each()` function.

But the function will consider my object to be an array, since the `lenght` property is present. What could I do in such a case?

Thank  you.

Comment: What do you mean, it considers the object to be an array? Seems to work just fine here https://jsfiddle.net/o6bw13yv/ (though you might consider ditching jQuery entirely for this, standard built-in methods work just fine)

Comment: `Object.keys(a)` will return array of the keys. You can then iterate through that.

Comment: It should be considered as a plain object and the magic that jQuery works will treat it as an iterable

Comment: `jQuery` doesn't check for a `length` property. I'm guessing it's doing `a instanceof Array` or `typeof a[Symbol.iterator] === "function"`

Comment: @CertainPerformance, if you could just provide what you put in a comment as an answer I would accept it. It is what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work perfectly in pure JS:

```
Object.keys(a).forEach(key => /* do something */);
```

If you really want to use jQuery for this:

```
$.each(Object.keys(a), (i, key) => /* do something */);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can skip a length property by checking the key name.

```
for (let key in a) {
    If (key !== ‘length’)  { do stuff }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a jquery implementation, please?